# CSS problem in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this problem when using CSS in IE8.  If I use CSS the textfields do not display on webpage.  If I do not use CSS the textfields are displayed.  All I'm doing is removing the styles from the HTML into a CSS file for 3 DIV's. Anyone know why I get this weird behavior?

The below part actually works. The style for "bannerOption1Div", "bannerOption2Div" and "bannerOption3Div" and in the HTML. The textfields are displayed and aligned.

```
<td align=center>
  <div class="bannerWrapper">
    <div id="bannerOption1Div"  width="10%" align=center style="display:none">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption1Source" id="bannerOption1SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px;  padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/>
      <font id="bannerOption1TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
    <div id="bannerOption2Div"  width="10%" align=center style="display:none">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption2Source" id="bannerOption2SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/> 
      <font id="bannerOption2TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
    <div id="bannerOption3Div"  width="10%" align=center style="display:none">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption3Source" id="bannerOption3SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/>
      <font id="bannerOption3TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Now all I did for "bannerOption1Div", "bannerOption2Div" and "bannerOption3Div" divs is moved their styles into a CSS class called "bannerSection" which causes problems.  The textfields are not displayed!!  Any help appreciated. Thanks.
Oh forgot, I have a javascript listener  that will display those textfields when the page is done loading.  So it will remove that display:none after page is done loading.  This also applies to the above HTML where it works.

Below is my CSS and the HTML.

```
.bannerSection{
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.bannerWrapper{
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
}


<td align=center>
  <div class="bannerWrapper">
    <div id="bannerOption1Div"  class="bannerSection">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption1Source" id="bannerOption1SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px;  padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/>
      <font id="bannerOption1TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
    <div id="bannerOption2Div"  class="bannerSection">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption2Source" id="bannerOption2SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/> 
      <font id="bannerOption2TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
    <div id="bannerOption3Div"  class="bannerSection">
      <input disabled=true type="text" name="bannerOption3Source" id="bannerOption3SourceId" size="20" style="height:20px; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"/>
      <font id="bannerOption3TextId" color="white" size="2" face="arial" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; display:block;">None</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

UPDATE:  ok a few answers pointed out that Javascript is the problem.  I think this is true.  So I switched in my Javascript the display property for the DIV from " " to "block" and the textfields now display.  But still the other two styles "width:10% and text-align: center" are broken.  Do I have to manually set them again in Javascript? Do they get deleted by Javascript?

```
fieldElement.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: You have `display: none;` as plain as day. Is this a trick question?

Comment: I just updated my question.  I actually have a javascript that will remove the display:none when the page is done loading.

Comment: Can we see the javascript? I would assume the problem is there.

Comment: yeah please look at my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your javascript is setting the `style` property of the elements to an empty string.
Which works when the styles are inline, but not when they are in css.

If this is the case, telling the javascript to set `display: static;` as the value for the `style` property should work.

Comment: When the page is loaded the javascript is doing this:  fieldElementID.style.display = "";   Shouldn't this only modify the display property for that DIV ?  I'm not too familiar with Javascript and CSS... just asking.

Comment: Yup javascript was the issue.  I was setting the style.diplsay to empty string and should instead have been block. thanks.

Comment: Heh, turns out I didn't answer at all... I'm still glad it was helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width for .bannerWrapper
That should make the percentage width and text-alignments of child elements make more sense.

Also, `<font>` tags make the baby jesus cry.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the css code in `<style></style>` tags

```
<style type="text/css">
.bannerSection{
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.bannerWrapper{
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: yeah the CSS file is done correctly. I just copied those two CSS classes, have other stuff there which works for other parts of the webpage.